# Cannot connect to wireless network

Tags: wireless

Changing my Gateway MX6448 laptop out from Windows XP

Downloaded Ubuntu 13.10.

Cannot find a way to get my wireless network be detected.

I have Broadcom BCM4311 wireless but cannot find any settings for it in the operating system. The wireless router that I am using is a Netgear n300 model # WNR2000.

I am also using a MacBook Pro and Mac Pro within the network. What can I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to download and install the driver from here 
[802.11 Linux STA driver | Broadcom](http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php)

Comment: The Broadcom STA driver is incorrect for his device.

Comment: Found in questions under the heading... Cannot connect to wireless network with a Broadcom BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN card ... I saw that the [14e4:4312] did not match up with what I had which was [14e4:4311]. Followed directions on that question, after the reboot, the wireless network came alive. Thank you.